# Windows 10 displaying incorrect last accessed time

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 files' last accessed time and date are behaving strangely,

for example:

1. The last accessed time for ALL files on my computer has been changed to the time of a restart upon restarting.
2. Right clicking on a file changes its last accessed time to the current time, I chose a folder to experiment with, I set it so that the files are listed and sorted by last accessed time, and merely right clicking on a file and refreshing the page would move the file to the top of the list.
3. Sometimes opening a file does not update the last accessed time, not even after a refresh.

So two questions:

1. Why is this the case and what can I try to do to fix this?
2. Could this be the work of a malware? Is there a way for me to check WHO accessed these files?

Thank You!

Comment: Most definitely wrong. Try a full scan with Windows 10 Defender.  Look hard for non-compliant or badly behaved software.  It is one of these causes - for sure not Windows 10. You can enable auditing (Local group policy) but that is not retroactive in any way.

Comment: @John I have scanned with windows 10 defender and malwarebytes, nothing turned up. I am very careful with the softwares I install and even websites I visit. I really want to say I'm 99.9% confident I didn't get a virus, but you never know nowadays...The only softwares I have downloaded on my computer are malwarebytes, vpn, games from steam, firefox and unity.

Comment: You might also check BIOS, power management and all drivers and update them all.

Comment: @John I will give it a try. If windows and malwarebytes both say I'm clean, how worry should I be if this is a virus? To be honest if I can know for sure that it's not a virus, I don't care that much about this glitch, so if I can just enable auditing to find out who is accessing the files I would be okay.

Comment: @John Ok, it turns out I do not have local group policy editor for some reason so I am unable to enable the audit policies. It's almost like.....something, or someone is preventing me from auditing and finding out what's going on.

Comment: You might consider backing up your machine and installing Windows fresh. The last time time was an issue for me, computers typically did not have clocks.

Comment: Last access time is not reliable.. depends on a setting on windows if it is used or not.  [Check this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/139015-enable-disable-ntfs-last-access-time-stamp-updates-windows-10-a.html) to ensure the current state of the policy.  I myself would not suspect a virus or malware because of strange behavior of this field.  Think about it.. wouldn't the date/time get updated just asking what it is?  Does it not ACCESS the file to find this out?

Comment: @Wonderman - Before you potentially reinstall Windows for no reason.  [This](https://github.com/builtbybel/PolicyPlus) might help edit your group policies

Answer (score 0):

If it is a local file instead of a shared folder\file, I would not think it access by other man, but we could audit it through configuration in Windows 10 system and check who access that folder\file through event viewer. For details steps, we could refer to: [How to Track Who Accesses, Reads Files on your Windows File Servers](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-who-read-files-on-your-windows-file-servers.html)

If there is no access history in event viewer but time was changed to last reboot time, I would more suspect it related with Windows 10 system. We also could run "sfc /scannow" or "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" to repair system files. Also we could update it through Setting\Update&Security\Windows Update to latest. But as least there is no need to worry about other people looking at the data. Hope that useful for you.